# When wifi to mobile net how to make it only notify once

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am doing a app about watching live video.When the net form wifi to mobile,I want to warn the user.I register a `BroadcastReceiver(android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE)`.I will warn the user when `networkInfo.getType != ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI`.But it will warn two or more times,But I only want to warn once.I see the `networkInfo.getType` will be `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE` or `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI`.I don't know it will be other.